# AngularJS service class - Good (right) or bad way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read lot of articles on the web about AngularJS and JS generally, and can't figure out the best way to make a service (like a class) the right way.

Is this a good or a bad way to do this (it works) - pros an cons?

```
.service('Field', function() {

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  function Field(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * Public method
   */
  Field.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
   * Public method
   */
  Field.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  return Field;
})


.controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, Field) {

  $scope.fields = [
    new Field(1, "Test1"),
    new Field(2, "Test2")
  ];

  console.log($scope.fields[0].getName());
})
```

I was inspired by this article - https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc

Comment: This is how I do it. Using prototype does produce better results and adds better intellisense features for IDEs that support it.

Comment: I think it is a good practice. There are several ways in Angular, its javascript. 

This way 

 - provide code reutilization
 - is testable,
 - follow the OOP js principles and the Angular Service principles
 - and as saying Mathew Foscarini, 

> using prototype does produce better results and adds better intellisense features for IDEs that support it. 

In conclusion, it is absolutely an acceptable way.